# Android ListView - How to refresh ListView when array is local files?

Tags: java, android, listview

I need some help, I have a list view app. In the list view, it loads local files (from a specific folder). Now the problem I'm facing that it's not refreshing when I delete a file or the app create a new file. The new file should add automatically in the list and the deleted file should go from the list, but it's not updating at all. Please help me!

**Issue update :** So the main problem I'm facing in the `notifydatasetchanged()` it's not working at all, the `observer` method is pretty accurate no issues in it!

**CAUTION :** It's 100% possible, if not then how file manager apps refresh their list view?

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_view);
        File appDir = new File( Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/App folder" );
        File filesDir = new File( appDir + "/Files" );
        if ( !appDir.exists()) {
            appDir.mkdir();
        }

        if ( !filesDir.exists()) {
            filesDir.mkdir();
        }

        File dir = new File(String.valueOf(filesDir));
        final File[] filelist = dir.listFiles();
        final String[] getFiles = new String[filelist.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < getFiles.length; i++) {
            getFiles[i] = filelist[i].getName();
        }

        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, getFiles);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);

        @SuppressLint("HandlerLeak") final Handler handler = new Handler() {
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {
                //to keep refreshing the list view
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        };
        TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
            }
        };
        timer.schedule(task, 1000, 500);
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to actually update the data in the adapter. `ArrayAdapter` has methods like lists `add()`, `remove()`, etc. You might want to delete and re-add all data (if it happens outside of your app) but of course that can be bad performance wise.

Comment: No, it's not deleting from outside, on long press on the files opens a context menu and on context menu option click ot deletes the file, but not refreshing the list!

Comment: then you have to call `adapter.remove(item)` before `notifityDataSetChanged()`

Comment: When I'm deleting the file I tried `adapter.remove(info.position);` + `adapter.notifityDataSetChanged();` but not working!

Comment: try `adapter.remove(adapter.getItem(info.position))`.

Comment: But It'll be better if I had an always refreshed adapter. I don't prefer this one!

Comment: Then you need to write code that refreshes your adapter when files change. You have to use FileObserver or similar. But your question was why the adapter does not refresh and the answer is: because you are not changing the data in your adapter. you are initializing it and then never change it. If you want the data to change, you have to change it. There is nothing in Adapter class that gives you that for free.

Answer (score 0):

You can register a **FileObserver** for particular path directory,when there is any change in that directory it will notify and you can refresh your list.

```
 FileObserver observer;
 List<String> fileList;
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_view);

        fileList=new ArrayList<>();
        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, fileList);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
          }


        loadDataFromPath();


        @SuppressLint("HandlerLeak") final Handler handler = new Handler() {
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {
                //to keep refreshing the list view
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        };
        TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
            }
        };
        timer.schedule(task, 1000, 500);

        File appDir = new File( Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/App folder" );
        File filesDir = new File( appDir + "/Files" );
      observer = initSingleDirectoryObserver(file.getAbsolutePath());
observer.startWatching();

}

 @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
    observer.stopWatching();
     super.onDestroy();
    }

public void loadDataFromPath()
{
 File appDir = new File( Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/App folder" );
        File filesDir = new File( appDir + "/Files" );
        if ( !appDir.exists()) {
            appDir.mkdir();
        }

        if ( !filesDir.exists()) {
            filesDir.mkdir();
        }

        File dir = new File(String.valueOf(filesDir));
        final File[] filelist = dir.listFiles();

        fileList.clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < getFiles.length; i++) {
           fileList.add(filelist[i].getName());
        }

         adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();



}

private FileObserver initSingleDirectoryObserver(String directoryPath) {
FileObserver observer = new FileObserver(directoryPath) {
            @Override 
            public void onEvent(int event, String file) {
                String filePath = dirPath + "/" + file;
                if (event == FileObserver.CREATE) {
                    loadDataFromPath();
                }else if (event == FileObserver.DELETE) {
                    loadDataFromPath();
                } 
            } 
        }; 
        return observer;
        }
```

Comment: No, I want a very simple method! It's too complicated!

Comment: I tried your code not refreshing! the observer is working but it's not refreshing!

Comment: and if you set `lv.setadapter(adapter)` in the `loadDataFromPath` it goes blank!

Comment: have you checked size of getFiles ?

Comment: Still the same problem as in the original code. You have to actually change the data in the adaper. e.g: `adapter.clear(); adapter.addAll(fileList); adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

Comment: Yes, they are 1kb text files :p... and the problem is in the adapter, we have to clear it and refresh it!

Comment: at the end of `loadDataFromPath()` where it currently only does `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`

Comment: It crashing! let's recall the old method! refresh the adapter in every 1 second! what about that? is it possible?